# How to load image from URL from variable source in C# xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I am doing app that will load URLs that user added. App will load URLs from database and show them images but when i put variable in image source it shows nothing and when  Itry to put url directly like this Source = "/memory/....". It shows it. It should look like this:

[image]

Code looks like this:

[image]

How to load these images from URL variable?

Comment: You can use libraries such as FFImageLoading, Glide etc. to achieve this. However, your question as is. Doesn't provide a minimal reproducible example of your issue, and as such I have marked it to be closed, since it is not well fit for StackOverflow QA. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please do NOT post code as images

Comment: use `ImageSource.FromUri()` to load from a url

Comment: FYI regarding formatted text vs images of text: Please read this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which lists many reasons why this is very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338/jason) mentioned in his comment on your question, just repalce the `FromFile(...)` in line 43 of image 2 with `FromUri(...)`.

See the docu of teh function here, [Docs MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource.fromuri?view=xamarin-forms)